# sqlite3 'cursor.execute' makes slash command unresponsive (discord.py)

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am coding a discord bot and I added slash command. I use sqlite3 to create a database.

One of the commands is problematic as it returns `The application did not respond` on Discord. I checked what went wrong in the code by adding some print statement and realized it was because of `cursor.execute`. Here is the code:

```py
@commands.hybrid_command(name='addoc', with_app_command=True)
# @commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=60, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def addoc(self, ctx: CustomContext, name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture: discord.Attachment):
        """ Add OC to the database with respect to user and guild id """
        # Get guild and user roles
        guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
        user_roles = extract_role_ids(ctx.message.author.roles)  # roles formatting needed to only keep the actual id
        print('check 1')
        try:
            # Check if permissions have been set for the server
            roles_list = self.roles_dict[guild_id]
            # Check is user is allowed to use the database
            print('check 2')
            if any(role in roles_list for role in user_roles):
                user_id = ctx.message.author.id

                print('check 3')
                cursor = self.db.cursor()
                print('check 4')
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "guild_{}" VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'.format(guild_id), (name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture.url))
                print('check 5')
                self.db.commit()

                # Close cursor
                cursor.close()
                self.db.close()


                await ctx.send(f'Character successfully added for <@{user_id}>!')

            else:
                await ctx.send("**If you think you should be able to add a character to the database, contact your local admins.**")

        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("**Please set the authorized roles first with `addrole` before adding an OC.**")
```

The code for some reason is too slow at check 4 and the slash command just stops (*check 5* isn't printed).

I did not have this issue before adding slash command so is there a way to fix this? By making the code faster in some way?

I thought it might come from the picture input, soI added a `.url` to only get the link but this didn't fix the issue.

**EDIT 1: I have good contact with the developer behind the postgreslite. He made sure everything was asynchronous and updated the library. I also tried `ctx.defer` but the bot just keep thinking indefinitely without sending a response. I said that already but I did not have any issue when it was not a slash command (`commands.command()` instead of `hybrid_command(name='addoc', with_app_command=True)`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was coming from SQL because I had set `user_id` as a primary key. Adding a `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to the table solved the problem. I also made sure I had the correct number of rows (I was missing `guild_id`).

Answer (score 3):

Since `discord.py` is asynchronous, the built-in `sqlite3` because it is synchronous, blocks the [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html).

To fix your problem try using the [`aiosqlite`](https://pypi.org/project/aiosqlite/) library instead.

```py
import aiosqlite

@commands.hybrid_command(name='addoc', with_app_command=True)
# @commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=60, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def addoc(self, ctx: CustomContext, name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture: discord.Attachment):
        """ Add OC to the database with respect to user and guild id """

        guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
        user_roles = extract_role_ids(ctx.message.author.roles)

        try:
            roles_list = self.roles_dict[guild_id]

            if any(role in roles_list for role in user_roles):
                user_id = ctx.message.author.id

                async with aiosqlite.connect(...) as db:
                    await db.execute('INSERT INTO "guild_{}" VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'.format(guild_id), (name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture.url))
                    await db.commit()

                await ctx.send(f'Character successfully added for <@{user_id}>!')
            else:
                await ctx.send("**If you think you should be able to add a character to the database, contact your local admins.**")

        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("**Please set the authorized roles first with `addrole` before adding an OC.**")
```

Another issue might be because your command takes more than 3 seconds to send a message. You can defer your interaction to have up to 15 minutes to send a message rather than the standard 3 seconds.

```py
@commands.hybrid_command(name='addoc', with_app_command=True)
# @commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=60, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def addoc(self, ctx: CustomContext, name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture: discord.Attachment):
        """ Add OC to the database with respect to user and guild id """
        await ctx.defer()  # defer response, now we have 15 minutes to reply

        guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
        user_roles = extract_role_ids(ctx.message.author.roles)

        try:
            roles_list = self.roles_dict[guild_id]

            if any(role in roles_list for role in user_roles):
                user_id = ctx.message.author.id

                async with aiosqlite.connect(...) as db:
                    await db.execute('INSERT INTO "guild_{}" VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'.format(guild_id), (name, age, nationality, gender, sexuality, universe, desc, picture.url))
                    await db.commit()

                await ctx.send(f'Character successfully added for <@{user_id}>!')
            else:
                await ctx.send("**If you think you should be able to add a character to the database, contact your local admins.**")

        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("**Please set the authorized roles first with `addrole` before adding an OC.**")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what seems weird is how the slash command causes issue, whereas classic command with prefix doesn't. Also this didn't work, the bot still can't get through the slash command.

Comment: Hm, how long does it take to do all the database stuff? more or less than 3 seconds?

Comment: For some reason it takes more than 3 seconds. I heard the slash command would just stop if it takes more than 3 seconds. But I don't understand why this isn't working when the "normal command" with a prefix was.

Comment: I also updated mine @Łukasz Kwieciński ^^